# antagonistic simulated annealing

Tags: optimization, conditional-probability, simulation, gibbs, simulated-annealing

[Simulated annealing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192492/justification-of-simulated-annealing-versus-random-search) aims at a series of target distributions
$$\pi_T(x)\propto\exp\{T\,H(x)\}$$
to find the maximum of the function $H$ and its argument
$$\arg_x\max_{x\in \mathfrak X} H(x)$$
if the temperature $T$ increases [slowly enough](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349270/simulated-annealing-parameter-tuning). When $\mathfrak X$ is of large dimension, it is usual to apply a Gibbs sampler to divide the simulation from $\exp\{T\,H(x)\}$ into smaller dimension targets.

Consider now solving the saddle-point problem
$$\arg_{(x_1,x_2)}\max_{x_1\in \mathfrak X_1}\min_{x_2\in \mathfrak X_2} H(x_1,x_2)$$
One can attempt a Gibbs sampling strategy with an increasing sequence of temperatures $T$ by simulating successively
$$X_2^{(t)}|X_1^{(t)}=x_1^{(t)}\sim  \exp\{-T\,H(x_1^{(t)},x_2)\}$$
and
$$X_1^{(t+1)}|X_2^{(t)}=x_2^{(t)}\sim  \exp\{+T\,H(x_1,x_2^{(t)})\}$$
but I wonder at the justification (and convergence) of this strategy given that the two Gibbs conditionals are not compatible with a joint but instead antagonistic.

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/simulated-annealing-proof-of-convergence

Comment: @MarkL.Stone: thank you for the link. Downhill simulated annealing is essentially the same as uphill simulated annealing, while saddlepoint simulated annealing remains a mystery (to me at least).

Comment: Not a solution, but - https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06277 - is some recent work which studies  certain algorithms for solving saddle-point problems, consisting of greedy ascent / descent steps, with noise injected. Their Theorem 1 shows that such a procedure can converge to an invariant measure. This might be useful.